# Meteor HTTP.call returning incomplete / truncated response

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Using `HTTP.call()` on the server, I'm getting varying response lengths (for the same endpoint) even though the response headers contain a consistent `content-length`. In other words, the response is getting randomly truncated.

```js
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';

Meteor.methods({
    'getJSON': function(url) {
        return HTTP.call('GET', url);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add `forever: true` to `npmRequestOptions` in the `HTTP.call` options. Apparently, the HTTP module won't handle keep alive connections by default and this can lead to issues with larger / slower responses.

```js
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';

Meteor.methods({
    'getJSON': function(url) {
        let options = {
            npmRequestOptions: {
                forever: true,
            }
        };

        return HTTP.call('GET', url, options);
    }
});
```

- https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback
- https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html#HTTP-call